# How to show price using echo $block->getDisplayValue() in list.phtml file?

Tags: magento2, product-prices

I found product price which is showing on the single product page. And it's coming form `default.phtml` file inside `Catalog/product/price/amount/default.phtml`.

This code is using

`<?php echo $block->getDisplayValue(); ?>`

to display the price in that file.

Now i want to show this price in my product list page and when i am trying this code, show the product price. I am getting **$0.00** ?

Can anyone tell me why this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the following code in your **Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml**

```
<?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
```

I hope that was what you mean.

Comment: in access if i want to show this price based on cart rule..so can you please tell me the way to do that....

Comment: What do you mean with based on cart rule?

Comment: I mean i have applied cart rule (discount on product price if any bulk purchase) in the product. so is there any way to get the expected prices like (buy 1-10 balls and the price would be $3/ball , buy 11 -30 balls and the price would be $2.7/ball ) and so on..that is the thing that i want to show on the product list page. can we do this as like we have the price using above code which you suggest to me....

Comment: Im sorry, im verry late! You can do this with a custom function.